# Как вывести данные из одной таблицы на основании другой или объеденить?

Tags: php, mysql

В базе данных есть две таблицы:

1. **_url** с полем `type`
2. **_splash** с полями `id` и `name`

В скрипте данные с первой таблицы выводятся так: `$url->type`.

Как вместо `$url->type` вывести `name`, если `type` с первой таблицы совпадает с `id` из второй, т. е. данные в поле `type` берутся из `id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

насколько я понял `$url -> type` делает запрос в БД и просто выводит результат. Тогда стоит просто изменить ф-ю:

```
$sql = "SELECT name
    FROM __splash
    JOIN __url
    ON __splash.id = __url.type;"
//for MySQL
$rs = mysqli_query($sql); 
foreach($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs) as $key => $val) {
    echo $key . " :" . $val . "</br>";
}
```

если нужно по определенному `id` изменять тогда нужно в функцию передавать его значение `$id` а в запрос вконец добавить `WHERE __url.name = {$id}`. 
Ну или просто делать запросы к таблице `__splash` вместо `__url`.

Answer (score -2):

Вообще это делается через SQL, создается таблица view которая объединяет несколько таблиц в одну (используй join), а потом уже выводи из этой твоей таблицы.

Ссылки по теме:
[SQL Views](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp)
[SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: зачем писать то, что по сути не является ответом, при том что развернутый ответ был дан несколько дней назад?

Comment: Я написал как это делается правильно.

Ссылки по теме - 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?